# Flash Filter and Array Questions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, actionscript, adobe

I've made a few flash projects using arrays to generate levels. Most cases I just use the built-in drawRect() function for the graphics so I have a simple solid square box which is added to a holder (parent) movie-clip that has no graphics, it just sits at the (0, 0) position.

Now my main question is, with this kind of set-up, if I wish to add a simple dropShadow() filter to the child squares, is it best to apply it to the parent itself, or each individual child/square within the parent?

And on that note actually, is generating levels with arrays the more efficient way of making levels, cost wise. I always like working like this, but is this the desired way to make let's say, a platform game? Opposed to having movie-clips of the level/enemies/player hand-drawn in Photoshop or Flash itself. I always enjoyed the array method because I could change a '0' to a '1' (arbitrary numbers) and it would be the difference of a ladder and an enemy. But when it comes to a full complete game and cost of the CPU and level-design ease, is arrays still ideal?

Sorry if these questions are obvious and "nonintellectual" but I like to hear thoughts/opinions of others more experienced than I. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You should've asked this question in the gamedev.stackexchange.com site, but whatever. If the game is tile-based then storing the tile numbers in arrays or better, vectors is the best solution (from my point of view). I've made a few tile-based platformers in flash, and used 3 vectors for a level.

- BG Vector
- Tile Vector
- Object Vector (enemies, pickups, player etc)

Now for collision detection, I used the Tile Vector. But for detecting the contact with AIs, I used the `Rectangle` class. Seperating "layers" is a good practice, you don't have to worry about the tiles in the object vector for example, because you are using the object vector just to define the start positions of the objects, enemies etc on the level, thus you won't run through it every frame. Same with the BG Vector, you can build up complex backgrounds, parallax view etc with adding them to a container, and then never run through of that vector again.

Comment: That is surprisingly exactly what I do, but I just wasn't sure if making a bunch of levels that have lots of children/tiles for the background was too costly. Good to know that someone else does this. If I wanted a drop shadow on everything in the tile vector would I just traverse it with a loop and then just add it to every element individually? If I have a bunch of walls in the tile vector, say 50 tiles, is 50 drop shadows too much for Flash to handle? Thanks for the response and sorry for posting to the wrong place.

Comment: I'd rather add the shadow drop to the graphics. By the way, if you want high performance, then use a framework such as Starling, you can render hundreds of animations with 60fps.